# SharePoint Server Search Not Crawling

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

we recently moved some sites into a new farm, everything seems to be doing fine, but the search for reasons I can't identify are not crawling the migrated content. We're getting this message in our crawl log for every document:

http://xxx/sites/...announcements
The object was not found. (The item was deleted because it was either not found or the crawler was denied access to it.)

Of course the first thing I suspected was the crawler access account, so I logged into SharePoint with the account and was able to access via that URL just fine.  I tried upping permissions (even all the way up to Admin) but to no avail.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, long story short my alternate access mappings were mangled...